# GWT Error: RequestFactory ValidationTool must be run but MyRequestFactoryDeobfuscatorBuilder exists

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gwt

That error appears but not all the time. Validation is done and in my WEB-INF directory i have a file named MyRequestFactoryDeobfuscatorBuilder.class.

It is an Android application registering in a GAE Server for GCM. Every information i found say that the MyRequestFactoryDeobfuscatorBuilder.class is missing but i have it on the Server. (not in the app)

Here is the complete stackTrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: The RequestFactory ValidationTool must be run for the myProject.client.MyRequestFactory RequestFactory type
at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.vm.impl.Deobfuscator$Builder.load(Deobfuscator.java:59)
at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.vm.InProcessRequestFactory.<init>(InProcessRequestFactory.java:80)
at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.vm.RequestFactorySource.create(RequestFactorySource.java:43)
at myProject.Util.getRequestFactory(Util.java:331)
at myProject.DeviceRegistrar.getRequest(DeviceRegistrar.java:110)
at myProject.DeviceRegistrar.registerOrUnregister(DeviceRegistrar.java:54)
at myProject.GCMIntentService.onRegistered(GCMIntentService.java:53)
at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.handleRegistration(GCMBaseIntentService.java:296)
at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:197)
at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Well, if `MyRequestFactoryDeobfuscatorBuilder.class` is in your `WEB-INF` as you say, I'd bet it's on your server only, not in the Android app.

Comment: Hello Thomas. Didn't konw it has to be in the app. Where exactly should it be? And why is it working 99% percents of the time? thank you